# How to convert struct-Type into []interface{} for pgx.CopyFromSlice

Tags: go, casting

For copying data into a Postgres database, I collect all my data in a slice, which I then hand over to `pgx.CopyFrom`. `CopyFrom` requires a `CopyFromSource` which can be achieved with `CopyFromSlice` to which you have to pass a function which needs a function that returns for a given index the data of that "row". That's my `GetAsInterface` function below.

Currently I do it by listing all my struct's members, one after the other. Is there a more convenient and less verbose way? The sequence is identical after all.

My idea is to later have the column names as annotation to my `MbpImport` type in order to have a more maintainable code. Curently I have to list the members two times, once when defining the type and a second time when converting it to `[]interface{}`. I also have to keep track in another function, which returns the database column names, that those have the correct sequence. I hope an annotation will help me here as the annotation will move with every change in the struct.

```golang
type MbpImport struct {
    Partner_id           int
    Target_table         string
    Keystring            string
    Info_date            time.Time 
    Mbp                  string
    Mbp_id               int
    Client_id            string
    Status               string
    Spam_traps           int64
    Spam_traps_imp       bool
    Email_volume         int64
    Spam_clicks          int64
    Spam_clicks_imp      bool
    Inbox                int64
    Spam_filter          int64
    Spam_filter_imp      bool
    Dkim_missing         int64
    Dkim_errors          int64
    Dkim_imp             bool
    Dkim_simple_strict   int64
    Dkim_simple_relaxed  int64
}

type MbpImportRows struct {
    index map[string]map[string]map[string]int
    rows []MbpImport
}

func (data *MbpImportRows) GetAsInterface(index int) ([]interface{}, error) {
    return []interface{}{
        data.rows[index].Partner_id,
        data.rows[index].Target_table,
        data.rows[index].Keystring,
        data.rows[index].Info_date,
        data.rows[index].Mbp,
        data.rows[index].Mbp_id,
        data.rows[index].Client_id,
        data.rows[index].Status,
        data.rows[index].Spam_traps,
        data.rows[index].Spam_traps_imp,
        data.rows[index].Email_volume,
        data.rows[index].Spam_clicks,
        data.rows[index].Spam_clicks_imp,
        data.rows[index].Inbox,
        data.rows[index].Spam_filter,
        data.rows[index].Spam_filter_imp,
        data.rows[index].Dkim_missing,
        data.rows[index].Dkim_errors,
        data.rows[index].Dkim_imp,
        data.rows[index].Dkim_simple_strict,
        data.rows[index].Dkim_simple_relaxed,
    },
    nil
}
```

Comment: You have 3 options: #1 keep doing what you're doing; #2 generate the code; #3 use reflection.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva. "reflect" is what I chose.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the comment of @mkopriva and use reflect:

```golang
type MbpImport struct {
    Partner_id           int        `dbcol:"partner_id"`
    Target_table         string     `dbcol:"target_table"`
    Keystring            string     `dbcol:"keystring"`
    Info_date            time.Time  `dbcol:"info_date"`
    Mbp                  string     `dbcol:"mbp"`
    Mbp_id               int        `dbcol:"mbp_id"`
    Client_id            string     `dbcol:"client_id"`
    Status               string     `dbcol:"status"`
    Spam_traps           int64      `dbcol:"spam_traps"`
    Spam_traps_imp       bool       `dbcol:"spam_traps_imp"`
    Email_volume         int64      `dbcol:"email_volume"`
    Spam_clicks          int64      `dbcol:"spam_clicks"`
    Spam_clicks_imp      bool       `dbcol:"spam_clicks_imp"`
    Inbox                int64      `dbcol:"inbox"`
    Spam_filter          int64      `dbcol:"spam_filter"`
    Spam_filter_imp      bool       `dbcol:"spam_filter_imp"`
    Dkim_missing         int64      `dbcol:"dkim_missing"`
    Dkim_errors          int64      `dbcol:"dkim_errors"`
    Dkim_imp             bool       `dbcol:"dkim_imp"`
    Dkim_simple_strict   int64      `dbcol:"dkim_simple_strict"`
    Dkim_simple_relaxed  int64      `dbcol:"dkim_simple_relaxed"`
}

func (data *MbpImportRows) Columns() []string {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(new(MbpImport)).Elem()
    myStr := make([]string, s.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        myStr[i] = s.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("dbcol")
    }
    return myStr
}

func (data *MbpImportRows) GetAsInterface(index int) ([]interface{}, error) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(&data.rows[index]).Elem()
    result := make([]interface{}, s.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        result[i] = s.Field(i).Interface()
    }
    return result, nil
}
```